# Passing [CONST][] array to C function?

Tags: c, c99

I am designing a C function interface which involves a 2d array. 
The problem is, row dimension is constant, and column one should be user defined.

```
#define ROWS (65)
void init(int columns, float array[ROWS?][columns?])
{
   ...
}

void main()
{
    float array1[ROWS][30]; 
    float array2[ROWS][50]; 
    init(30, array1); 
    init(50, array2); 
}
```

How do I design an interface to be able to pass this kind of array down to function?

p.s.
Can't do it the other way around, where columns would be constant, because must use some 3rd pary libraries that want it this way.

Comment: Are you limited to a certain standard of C?

Comment: Yes, limited to C99.

Comment: For C11 and C99 you can just declare it as `void init(int columns, float array[ROWS][columns])`.

Comment: @haccks `#define ROWS (65)` is fine, although the parentheses are redundant if the macro is just being used as a constant.

Comment: "to pass this kind of array down to function?", listen me carefully, **you can't pass any array of any kind to any function in C**, this is simply impossible it's will always be a pointer.

Comment: @Stargateur Yes but it wll be a pointer of array type, or in this case a pointer of VLA type.

Comment: @Stargateur Except of course when you pass an array by value to a function in C `typedef struct { int array[ROWS]; } foo_t; ... void func (foo_t foo);`. That's a dirty hack though.

Comment: @Lundin Note that `foo` is not an array but a structure. So this is still not "you pass an array by value to a function in C", as I state is impossible ;) But your hack is funny I never see that in any code.

Comment: @Stargateur If you want to write truly evil (but well-defined) code, you could do `int array[ROWS]; func(*(foo_t*)array);` And then cast it back to an array type inside the function.

Answer (score 4):

Simply do as you wrote in your example

```
void init (size_t rows, size_t columns, float array[rows][columns])
```

Then you can pass compile-time constants or run-time variables to the function as you please. You'll also need to have C compiler from the current millennium (C99 or later).

Comment: `mingw32-g++.exe` gives error: `use of parameter outside function body before ']' token`. What about C++ compilers?

Comment: @Danijel C++ does not have VLA. This is tagged C so I gave a C answer. Compile the code with a C compiler.

Answer (score 3):

You mentioned [c99](/questions/tagged/c99) in a comment. So it shouldn't be too difficult to approximate what you want. In fact, you are almost there yourself. It can look like this:

```
#define ROWS 65
void init(int columns, float array[static ROWS][columns])
{

}
```

Now `array` is of a variably modified type, and `columns` is user defined. `static ROWS` means callers must pass in an array of at least 65 rows, or undefined behavior will ensue. That's pretty much as close to forcing them to pass `65` as you can.

Comment: Actually the static keyword here does nothing in practice, since the array will get adjusted to an array pointer before arguments are checked. To achieve some manner of increased type safety, neither your solution nor mine will do, but one has to make the parameter `float (*array)[rows][columns]`.

Comment: @Lundin - I have seen instances of Clang warning about improper arrays sizes when `static` is used, though for the life of me I can't recall the exact compiler switch. There is also the idiom of using `[static 1]` to better signal no null check will be perform, but YMMV. `float (*array)[rows][columns]` is just uncomfortable on the caller. I personally think the OP may want to avoid that if they are writing a library. But for sure, that's the way to go to force the type checking.

Comment: I suppose it isn't really specified when exactly the "array adjustment" of function parameters takes place. In gcc, `static` is completely superfluous unless used on one of the dimensions to the right, that don't get adjusted. It always seemed like a superfluous feature to me, much like `[*]` in function declarations.

Comment: @Lundin - I guess it's one of those features which the committee hoped implementations will use to improve diagnostics, when in practice they just don't bother. A global QoI issue.